# Spring boot - Set Solace password from code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, message-queue, spring-cloud-stream, solace

I have a Spring boot application that connects to a solace queue using a configuration similar to the below.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: emitSensorReading
    stream:
      poller:
        fixed-delay: 5000
      bindings:
        emitSensorReading-out-0:
          destination: sensor/temperature/fahrenheit
          binder: local-solace
      binders:
        local-solace:
          type: solace
          environment:
            solace:
              java:
                host: tcp://localhost:55555
                msgVpn: default
                clientUsername: default
                clientPassword: default
                connectRetries: -1
                reconnectRetries: -1
```

I want to read the password by connecting to an API rather than hard coding it to the application.yaml file. I have a REST service that will return the password. How can I set up my Spring boot application to make the solace connection by obtaining password from the REST service?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is something like a Config Server. It stores and serves configurations across multiple applications and environments. These configurations are ideally versioned under Git version control and can be modified at application runtime.

For more details please refer to the following documentation and examples:

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I went through the links and it seems this solution reads all properties from the server. Please correct me if I am wrong. I only need to get the password from the REST API and other properties from application.yaml . Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: If in the versioned configurations served by the Config Server you have only the password then all the other properties would be read from your application.yml.

Comment: Thanks, I can achieve my requirement with this. However, is there any other way I can do this without having this intermediary config server. Ideally, by connecting to the REST API by my spring boot app itself?

Comment: But which service will provide such a REST API if you don't have the Config Server?

Comment: I am using cyberark as a password store, so I want to get password from cyberark when running the application, rather than having it in the property yaml.

Comment: Ok, then I can't help you. I don't know cyberark. Sorry. But you might consider using Config Server instead.

Comment: It's just an API. When I call GET method with username, it is returning the password.

Comment: Then you need to use `RestTemplate` to call the API. Check details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

Comment: Yeah, but how to use the password retrieved from the API to set the solace connection is the problem I am having.

Comment: You would need to create the Solace related beans on your own. I would give Config Server a try instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first initialise the RestTemplate and then @Autowire it in your solace client. Then create a session for solace client in PostConstruct method as shown below

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPFactory;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPProperties;
import com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPSession;

@Service
public class SolaceClienExample {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    private JCSMPSession session;


    JCSMPProperties properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.properties = getJCSMPProperties();
        log.debug("Solace client instantiated with JCSMPProperties properties {}", this.properties);
        this.session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);
    }
    
    
     private JCSMPProperties getJCSMPProperties() {
        JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
        properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, "tcp://localhost:8080"); // host:port
        properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, "my-user"); // client-username
        properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.VPN_NAME, "solace-vpn"); // message-vpn
        properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.PASSWORD, getSolacePassword("my-user")); // client-password
        return properties;
     }
     
     public String getSolacePassword(String user){
         String requestUrl="https://url-for-password-get.com"+"/"+user;
         HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
         requestHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
         requestHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
         HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);
         ResponseEntity<PasswordResponseDto> passwordResponse= restTemplate.exchange(
                new URI(requestUrl), HttpMethod.GET, request, PasswordResponseDto.class);
         return passwordResponse.getPassword();
     }
}
```